# Content-Disposition attachment filename with blankspace in InterNet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, asp-classic

```
string filename = Server.UrlPathEncode(Path.GetFileName(_Filename)));
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + encodeURIComponent(filename) + "\"");
```

I wrote a code like this..

It Works Fine in all the browsers but in Internet Explorer when I click on save as It works fine but when click on open I get `%20` in the file name..

Can someone please let me know how to overcome this issue

Suppose if the File name is "New text Document.txt". When I open the file after download I want it with the same name. I do not want to see it as "New_text_Document.txt".

Is there way do this?

It works fine for me in other browsers. I am having only this problem in Internet Explorer. If I do not encode by default I will get the File name as  "New_text_Document.txt".

Answer (score 3):

If your filename contains spaces, they will be URL encoded.
The space characters encoded is actually %20 which we can see in the file name.

To avoid that, you could simply replace the spaces with another character, for example `_`.

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + 
   encodeURIComponent(filename.Replace(" ", "_")) + 
"\"");
```